# Proving $U_{\varepsilon}(a)\cap V_{\varepsilon}(b)=\emptyset$

Tags: real-analysis

I believe I have the right idea but having trouble formulating a mathematical argument for this proof.

> Suppose $a,b\in \mathbb{R}, a\neq b$.  Show there exists $\varepsilon$-neighborhoods $U_{\varepsilon}(a)$ and $V_{\varepsilon}(b)$ such that $U\cap V=\emptyset$

So i figure I start out saying, let $|b-a|>2\varepsilon$.  This establishes that the distance between $a$ and $b$ is more than the necessary $2\varepsilon$ distance.  Thus I need to find a number $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $a<x<b$ where $x\notin U, V$.  I'm supposing this number is $\frac{b-a}{2}$.

But now how do I show that $\frac{b-a}{2}\notin (a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)$ and $\frac{b-a}{2}\notin (b-\varepsilon,b+\varepsilon)?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine this geometrically. Say there are two points $a, b$ on the line. Find the distance between the points and halve it. If you draw two open balls (circles such that it does not contain points on its perimeter) centered at each point with radius equal to half the distance between them then will they intersect??

Let $\left|{a - b}\right| = d \gt 0$ since $a \neq b$. Let $U_{\epsilon}(a) = \left|{x - a}\right| \lt \frac d 2$ and $V_{\epsilon}(b) = \left|{x - b}\right| \lt \frac d 2$ where $\epsilon = \frac d 2$ This is exactly what you suggested btw.

Now let's show that they are disjoint.

Say $y \in U_{\epsilon}(a)$ and $y \in V_{\epsilon}(b)$

Since, $y \in U_{\epsilon}(a) \implies \left|{y - a}\right| \lt \frac d 2\implies \left|{(a - b) - (y - b)}\right| \lt \frac d 2 \implies \left|{a - b}\right| - \left|{y - b}\right| \lt \frac d 2 \implies d - \left|{y - b}\right| \lt \frac d 2 \implies \frac d 2 \lt \left|{y - b}\right| \implies y \not \in V_{\epsilon}(b)$ leading to a contradiction.

$\implies V_{\epsilon}(b) \cap U_{\epsilon}(a) = \emptyset$

Your logic is false, since finding just one number which is not in both $U$ and $V$ does not prove that they are disjoint. You need to prove there are no common points in the two neighbourhoods.

Comment: The last part of your post, showing that they are disjoint, is what I could not get my head around.  Thank you for making it clear and concise.  I fear that being able to do that might be difficult because I would have never thought to do what you did.  But I can see how you incorporated the b variable in step 3 and eliminated a so you could set up the contradiction.  Very nice.

Comment: @Faffi-doo: I believe you are taking a first calculus course. It can't hurt to properly familiarise yourself with triangle inequalities and its uses. Maybe I can recommend a book . *Spivak*'s *Calculus*?? Anyway keep doing more problems. I had the same issue not so long ago. Not too hard to rectify..

Comment: I've taken Calc before.  My calculus course focused on formulae, not proofs.  This is a first year analysis course, and we are using Bartle's Intro to Real Analysis.

Comment: Okay then I will advise it can't hurt to look through the first few chapters of the book I recommended because you might have trouble getting through Bartle.. You need to use inequalities a lot in the second chapter..

Comment: I will check it out.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: By the way, this is the second chapter!!  Having trouble... (i'm sure you can tell if you look at all my previous posts)

Comment: @Faffi-doo: It's nothing to worry about. I mean I'm no expert. Just completed my first year in college. And I've doubted myself exactly as you have - still do actually - but trust me you will progress. Like I said here - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682934/simple-proof-exercise-recommendation-with-full-answers/682943#682943 - there are no shortcuts. Just keep looking for problems and spend time solving them..

Comment: @Faffi-doo: And one more advice. Like I said try to visualise the question geometrically and see if it makes sense. Then if you've convinced yourself why it's true in a geometric sense then there must surely be a rigorous proof for it. That's how I go about it. Works most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\left|b-\frac{b-a}2\right|=\left|\frac{2b-b+a}2\right|=\left|\frac{b+a}2\right|>\frac{2\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon.
$$
Therefore $\frac{b-a}2$ doesn't live in $(b-\varepsilon,b+\varepsilon)$, since it's too far away. Similar argument for the interval around $a$.

See below for a more thorough answer, though.

Comment: This shows $\frac{b-a}{2}$ is neither in $U$ nor in $V$, but it doesn't show $U\cap V$ is empty.

Comment: Well I answered his question, that this midpoint isn't in either of them. I would add more at the asker's prompting.

Comment: OK, fair enough... though of course the question he asked at the end is actually the wrong question, as I'm sure you realised.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me as if your main difficulty is with the logic rather than the algebra/analysis.  This is very common in beginning analysis proofs and it's worth spending some time on it.  So here are **some hints**.

First your statement "This establishes that the distance between $a$ and $b$ is more than the necessary $2\varepsilon$ distance".  This is not exactly wrong but it sounds as if you are trying to prove something about a pre-specified $\varepsilon$.  In fact, you have to choose an $\varepsilon$, and this idea is your basis for choosing it.  So you could say something like "choose some positive $\varepsilon<\frac{1}{2}|b-a|\,$".

Next, you say that you have to find **some** $x$ such that $x\notin U$ and $x\notin V$.  But this does not mean $U\cap V=\varnothing$.  In fact, you have to prove that **no** $x$ is in both $U$ and $V$.  **Hint**.  Assume $x\in U$ and $x\in V$, and derive a contradiction, using the value of $\varepsilon$ you chose earlier.

Comment: Since the proof begins by establishing that $a<b$, this means I don't need the absolute value sign?  Can I just say "Choose $\varepsilon<\frac{b-a}{2}$?

Comment: Unless I missed something, it's not actually given that $a<b$.  However it's fairly clear that it doesn't matter which of $a$ and $b$ is bigger, so you could begin the proof by saying "without loss of generality $a<b\,$".

Answer (score 0):

Let be $\epsilon = \frac{|b-a|}{4}$. Take balls centered on $a$ and $b$ with radium $\epsilon$.