# Mathematics books containing simple proof exercises

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

So I just came from this page: https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682934/a-book-with-simple-proof-exercises-and-full-answers&hl=en-ID

and want to ask something related to math books that contain easy proving exercises.

In that page, the book by Solow was mentioned. I am able to prove most of the exercises there, but I have to admit that for "newcomers" in mathematics, this book has only a few easy or elementary proof exercises, even though it explains proving nicely. I do not mean to say that the book has to have answers to all exercises which usually are there at the end of the book, but does someone have any book recommendation?

I just want to know if there is any type of book that contains elementary proof problems, not necessarily more examples, but more simple exercises. This would be very helpful to recommend for my students.
An additional websites recommendation works too..

Thanks a lot. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How to Prove it" by Velleman is a nice gentle introduction to proof writing.  Also, many exercises in beginning discrete math books are excellent practice for honing proof-writing skills.  For example, Concrete Mathematics is a great place to start.

Comment: Oh wow I haven't thought about discrete math books. Thanks a lot..